# SOQL error "cannot have more than one level of relationships"

Tags: apex, soql

I have a `Facility` object that has a relationship with `Department` object. Now I created a new object to give users access on these facilities.

I'm trying to retrieve `Facility` data to a list, but I want just to retrieve the facilities that has departments User has access on.

Department object

```
_____________________________________
|    ID     |   Name   |   Facility  |

|   dep1    |  IT dep  |   Facility1 |
|   dep2    |  HR dep  |   Facility2 |
|   dep3    |  SC dep  |   Facility1 |
```

access_object

```
_________________________
| User  |  department   |

| hasan |    dep1       |
| jack  |    dep2       |
```

This what I tried and gave me this error in the title

```
Facility = [SELECT ID, Name 
            FROM Facility__c 
            WHERE ID IN (SELECT Department__r.Facility__c 
                         FROM Access_object__c 
                         WHERE User__c =: UserInfo.getUserId())];
```

Answer (score 2):

Try reworking the query to start from Access_object__c and then [group](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_groupby.htm) the resulting facility ids and names.

```
select Department__r.Facility__c, Department__r.Facility__r.Name 
from Access_object__c 
where User__c = :UserInfo.getUserId()
group by Department__r.Facility__c, Department__r.Facility__c.Name
```

Comment: Is it allowed to use group by like this ? it doesn't accept the brackets **(** with it.

Comment: You can use multiple ORDER BY fields, but don't use the parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative way to do it

```
{
List<Access_object__c > ao = new List<Access_object__c >();
Facility__c temp_facility = new Facility__c();
boolean exist;
ao =[SELECT Department__r.Facility__c, Department__r.Facility__r.Name, Department__r.Facility__r.Name__c 
     FROM Access_object__c WHERE User__c =: UserInfo.getUserId()];

for(Access_object__c a: ao){
  exist = false;
  temp_facility  = [SELECT ID, Name, Name__c FROM Facility__c
                      WHERE ID =: u.Department__r.Facility__c];
  for(Facility__c it_facility: facility){
    if(it_facility.ID == temp_facility.ID)
      exist = true;
  }

  if(!exist)
    Facility.add(temp_facility);

  temp_facility = new Facility__c();
}// At the end I will have a list called "facility" that has the required data
```